# Data grouping by date and converting DateTime to Double

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

can anyone help me with this, I'm getting the result at the moment:

[image]

I want the data in the Stunden column to convert to Double and sort by date
At the end result to be 01.03.2017 = 9.0; 
                    
13.12.2017 = 8.5;

this is my current code

```
q.ZPZ_LPE_ID = userID;
            if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                db.Open();
            string query = "SELECT zei.ZPZ_Von, zei.ZPZ_Bis, per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum, SUM (zei.ZPZ_Std100) AS ZPZ_Std100" +
                           " FROM DB.dbo.Z_PRAESENZZEIT zei INNER JOIN DB.dbo.A_PERSONAL per ON zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID = per.LPE_ID" +
                            $" WHERE zei.ZPZ_Datum BETWEEN '{dtFromDate.Value}' AND '{dtToDate.Value}' AND zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID='{userID.ToString()}' GROUP BY per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum, zei.ZPZ_Von, zei.ZPZ_Bis ORDER BY zei.ZPZ_Datum, per.LPE_Nr;";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, db))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        var items = new BindingList<PRAESENZZEIT>();
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            PRAESENZZEIT pra = new PRAESENZZEIT();

                            pra.ZPZ_Datum = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Datum"]);
                            pra.ZPZ_Von = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Von"]);
                            if (pra.ZPZ_Von.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(8, 5, 0))
                                pra.ZPZ_Von = new DateTime(pra.ZPZ_Von.Year, pra.ZPZ_Von.Month, pra.ZPZ_Von.Day, 8, 0, 0);

                            // DateTime gehen = DateTime.Now;
                            pra.ZPZ_Bis = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Bis"]);
                            pra.arbeitszeit = pra.ZPZ_Bis - pra.ZPZ_Von;
                           // Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(arbeitszeit));

                            items.Add(pra); 
                        }
                        pRAESENZZEITBindingSource.DataSource = items;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

this is the PRAESENZEIT class

```
public class PRAESENZZEIT
{
    public int LPE_Nr { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_Datum { get; set; }
    public double ZPZ_Std100 { get; set; }
    public int ZPZ_LPE_ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime ZPZ_Von { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_Bis { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_Std { get; set; }

    public int ZPZ_ID { get; set; }
    public int ZPZ_Jahr { get; set; }
    public int ZPZ_Monat { get; set; }
    public int ZPZ_Tag { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_ERFDAT { get; set; }
    public string ZPZ_ERFUSER { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_MUTDAT { get; set; }
    public string ZPZ_MUTUSER { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan arbeitszeit { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you all for help

mysql query result 
[image]

Comment: is Stunden refer to hour?

Comment: @RenéVogt you have the right, I'll fix it

Comment: @JericCruz yes "Stunden" is German for "hours".

Comment: is there a key/flag to know whether it is a in or out? I assume that it is a timer app, that employee needs to punch log in or out. That can be done in sql statement

Comment: so you want to "GROUP BY" day?

Comment: @JericCruz that you are in charge, it's about calculating working time for a worker .. I only need at the end of the day the score for the whole day 04:00:00 + 05:00:00 = 9.0

Comment: @Mat yes, grouping per day

Comment: May i ask for a [mcve] next time? Because here the data were a picture, for a result with 2 column you show us a full class with german name every where.

Comment: I added the result of the sql query that is in the database @DragandDrop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to group by day. You can check if you already added the day and add the time to `arbeitszeit`. However then the fields 'von' and 'bis' are useless. This is basically because the class design is quite bad. You could have a class `ArbeitsTag` which contains a property `List<Anwesenheit>` and a property `Gesamtzeit` aka `Totaltime` where you sum up all the times. But that's a different story ;-)

```
var items = new BindingList<PRAESENZZEIT>();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        PRAESENZZEIT pra = null;


                        DateTime datum = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Datum"]);

                        //calculate parse from and to. Don't store it to Präsenzzeit as it will be accumulated. Therefore it will always be wrong. possible solution would be to store each "phase" separatly and calculate a Total time from there...
                        DateTime von = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Von"]);
                        if (von.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(8, 5, 0))
                            von = new DateTime(von.Year, von.Month, von.Day, 8, 0, 0);

                        DateTime bis = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Bis"]);

                         pra = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ZPZ_Datum == datum);
                        //check if day was already added
                        if (pra != null)
                        {
                            pra.arbeitszeit = pra.arbeitszeit + (bis - von);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            pra = new PRAESENZZEIT();

                            pra.ZPZ_Datum = datum;

                            // DateTime gehen = DateTime.Now;

                            pra.arbeitszeit = bis - von;
                            // Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(arbeitszeit));

                            items.Add(pra);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If Studen is a TimeSpan you can sum it that way.

```
var dataSource = new List<grdata> {
     //         StartDate         , EndDate
     new grdata("01/03/2017 04:00","01/03/2017 08:00"),
     new grdata("01/03/2017 09:00","01/03/2017 14:00"),
     new grdata("13/12/2017 04:30","13/12/2017 09:00"),
     new grdata("13/12/2017 10:00","13/12/2017 14:00")
};

var opdata = dataSource.Select(x => new
{
    date = DateTime.Parse(x.start.ToShortDateString())                ,
    time = x.end-x.start
});

var result = opdata.GroupBy(x => x.date)
                    .Select(g => new
                    {
                        date = g.Key,
                        sumTime = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(y => y.time.Ticks))
                    });

var totalSum = new TimeSpan(opdata.Sum(y => y.time.Ticks));
```

Result:

```
{ date = {01/03/2017 00:00:00}, sumTime = {00:09:00} }
{ date = {13/12/2017 00:00:00}, sumTime = {00:08:30} }
```

Comment: I do not understand how to apply you example, can you see how my query in the database looks up

Comment: can you please look at my code up, I do not understand how I can apply this example?

Comment: This is what i mean by [Mcve], Cut all the fluff. Abstract the problem with a simple type,. Provide information sample that people can copy past(not picture). Use English name. If I had wrote that in French you woud still be asking for clarification.

Comment: Do you mean rewrite that answer using variable type and laguage that is a stranger to me? 
Im fluent only in French, english, creole and a little bit of klingon.. will klingon be okay?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not manage to find a solution for myself, thank you for your support! @Drag and Drop